# Wicket ListView with AjaxSelfUpdateTimerBehaviour

Tags: java, ajax, listview, wicket

I want to use a ListView with an AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior. I have a form that takes a location and some files to upload with MultiFileUploadField. After that, I have a web service witch is going to store them. So when I click the submit button, I have a modal window that appears. It contains my list view. This list has to be updated when the web service is done. My problem is when I set the AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior, when I try it, it waits the number of seconds mentioned in `new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` then the list disappears. I tried this

[1]: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+repaint+a+ListView+via+Ajax but in vain. I use Wicket 6.8.0.

Here's the Markup

```
<div class="modal-body" style="display: table-cell;">

    <table wicket:id="wholeTable">      
        <tr wicket:id="files">
            <td width="30"><span wicket:id="ajaxSpinner"><img
                    src="../img/ajax-loader.gif" /></span><span
                wicket:id="orderValid"><img
                    src="../img/ok-16.png" /></span><span
                wicket:id="orderFailed"><img
                    src="../img/ok-16.png" /></span></td>
            <td wicket:id="container" style="opacity:0.4"><span wicket:id="putMessage"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here's the Java code

```
WebMarkupContainer wholeTable = new WebMarkupContainer("wholeTable");

    IModel<ArrayList<FileUpload>> inputFilesModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<ArrayList<FileUpload>>() {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<FileUpload> load() {
            return (ArrayList<FileUpload>) inputFiles;
        }

    };
    ListView<FileUpload> fileList = new ListView<FileUpload>("files", inputFilesModel) {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<FileUpload> item) {
            final FileUpload file = (FileUpload) item.getModelObject();
            WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
            item.add(container);
            item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("ajaxSpinner"));
            item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("orderValid"));
            item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("orderFailed"));
            item.get("orderValid").setVisible(false);
            item.get("orderFailed").setVisible(false);
            container.add(new Label("putMessage", "dépôt de l'archive " + file.getClientFileName()));
        }
    };
    wholeTable.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    // Update the whole panel every two second
    wholeTable.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)));
    wholeTable.add(fileList);
    target.add(wholeTable);
    add(wholeTable);
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance for your answers and sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the second time you load 'inputFiles' this list is empty? Causing the table to render an empty list, ie not render any item.

Comment: I didn't thought about it. How can I do to make it don't load a second time or make it load something that is not empty the second time?. Thanks

Comment: That depends on how `inputFiles` is filled. Can you show the code surrounding that list?

Comment: inputFiles is filled as an argument in the constructor. I'll show the code monday, I can't access it now.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that to correctly use AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior you should override 'onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget)' method and add the elements you want refreshed (in your case - wholeTable) to it's AjaxRequestTarget.

EDIT:

Change your line:

```
wholeTable.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)));
```

To:

```
wholeTable.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)) {
    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       target.add(wholeTable);
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot see how to do this exactly. I tried extending AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior but I couldn't override the onTimer method since I'm using wicket 6.8.0 and like it's said here  [doc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html), the method is final. So how can I override it and could you be more specific about the content of the overridden method. Thank you

Comment: Check my edit. In doc you linked 'onTimer()' method is marked as protected not final.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer but like I said it's final. Please see in the doc I linked the details of the method onTimer(), you'll find it's final. But I also extended the AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior class and put in it [AjaxSelfUpdateTimerBehaviour.java]
(http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/6.8.0/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.java#AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior) and added to the onTimer() method the line you specified.